# How come I can't read from my socket buffer UWP

Tags: uwp, stream-socket-client

I'm trying to write a DLL file to handle sockets for my UWP apps, much like I did for my winforms apps.  Problem is I'm just getting into writing UWP apps.  My original socket control DLL file would start a receive thread, and every 100 milliseconds, read from the socket and raise an event.  I tried doing the same thing in my UWP DLL, but it doesn't seem to work with the code I copied from the MSDN website.  Can someone take a look and see what I'm doing wrong?  I'm not going to lie, I've never used a task before (threads seemed easier).

PS, I've confirmed that connecting and sending data works.

EDIT: Changed my code slightly.  But still doesn't work.  Any ideas folks?

Doesn't seem to be going past the below line, even when data is sent to it.

Dim DataText As String = Reader.ReadToEnd

```
Imports Windows.Networking

Imports Windows.Networking.Sockets

Public Class ClientSocket

Private CSocket As New StreamSocket

Dim strHost As String = "192.168.0.11"

Dim RPort As String = "80"

Private killswitch As Boolean = False

Public Event SocketError(ByVal Operation As String, ByVal ErrorMessage As String)

Public Event DataReceived(ByVal DataString As String)

Public Async Sub Connect()

    Try

        Dim RHost As HostName = New HostName(strHost)

        Await CSocket.ConnectAsync(RHost, RPort)

        ReceiveTask.Start()

    Catch ex As Exception

        RaiseEvent SocketError("Connecting", ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub

Public Sub Disconnect()

    killswitch = True

    CSocket.Dispose()

End Sub

Public Async Sub SendText(ByVal SendString As String)

    Try

        Dim OutStream As Stream = CSocket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite

        Dim Writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(OutStream)

        Await Writer.WriteLineAsync(SendString)

        Await Writer.FlushAsync

    Catch ex As Exception

        RaiseEvent SocketError("Sending", ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub

Private ReceiveTask As New Task(Sub()

                                    Dim InStream As Stream = CSocket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead

                                    Dim Reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(InStream)

                                    While killswitch = False

                                        Try

                                            Dim DataText As String = Reader.ReadToEnd

                                            RaiseEvent DataReceived(DataText)

                                        Catch ex As Exception

                                            RaiseEvent SocketError("Receiving", ex.Message)

                                        End Try

                                        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))

                                    End While

                                End Sub)

Public Property Host As String

    Get

        Host = strHost

    End Get

    Set(value As String)

        strHost = value

    End Set

End Property

Public Property Port As String

    Get

        Port = RPort

    End Get

    Set(value As String)

        RPort = value

    End Set

End Property

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with the below code in the Receive Task:

```
    Private ReceiveTask As New Task(Sub()

                                    Dim InStream As Stream = CSocket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead

                                    While killswitch = False

                                        Try

                                            Dim Reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(InStream)

                                            Dim DataText As String = ""

                                            While Reader.Peek <> -1

                                                DataText &= Convert.ToChar(Reader.Read)

                                            End While



                                            RaiseEvent DataReceived(DataText)

                                        Catch ex As Exception

                                            RaiseEvent SocketError("Receiving", ex.Message)

                                        End Try

                                    End While

                                End Sub)
```